# 500 error while creating a pull request

Tags: github

I always get "500 error " whenever I try to create a pull request on my fork in github, I just keep on trying it, at some point the page loads(it is . Is there any update or something that I have to do.?

My fork is uptodate with the branch I forked from. No clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue -- going to `https://github.com/[your account]/[repository]/pull/new` and creating a PR from that page worked for me.

Comment: Update: After notifying Github support about this, they investigated and pushed a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the url for 500 error was like https://github.com/[your account]/[repository]/pull/new/[branch].

You can avoid 500 error by accessing via a URL like https://github.com/[your account]/[repository]/pull/new, then you can choose a branch to send pull request from and to.